# How to take values from one MySQl table, multiply them together, and put the results in another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 4 rows, I need to multiply col. 1 and 2 and put the results in col. 1 in the 2nd table. do the same with the other two cols' from table 1.

I'm sure its simple code. I just don't know MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Get the values fetch the rows and insert again to the table 2:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'tu_usuario', 'tu_contraseña', 'sakila');

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->connect_errno . "\n";
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->connect_error . "\n";
    exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT column1, column2 FROM table1";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {

    /* fetch object array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()){
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO table2 (col1) VALUES(".$row['column1']*$row['column2'].");";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    }


}
```

I didn't check if there is any error in theses code, it's just an example that shows the idea. I hope will be enough for you the explanation. If you still having doubts please answer again.

Comment: This can also be done directly in MySQL, but your solution is more flexible